# Using heap in ruby algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm, heap, hashtable, nodes

Working on the following algorithm:

> Given a non-empty array of integers, return the k most frequent
>   elements.
>
> For example, Given [1,1,1,2,2,3] and k = 2, return [1,2].
>
> Note:  You may assume k is always valid, 1 ≤ k ≤ number of unique
>   elements. Your algorithm's time complexity must be better than O(n log
>   n), where n is the array's size.

My initial impulse is to use a hash table for number as the key and the value as the number of occurrences. Then, I can insert each key-value pair as a node into a maxHeap and simply delete max until k == 0.

Is building a node and inputting into a maxHeap the right way to solve with that approach? **Note I'm not curious about a more optimal solution-- curious about whether that's the way I'd implement the idea of using maxHeap to repeatedly find the number with the maximum number of occurrences.** The node part seems like overkill but I'm not sure how else to do it.

Comment: This sounds to me like the right approach. Basically your problem boils down to "find k largest elements in an array", which is normally solved either by quickselect (but that's O(n^2) worst case) or by using a heap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer:**

code:

```
input = [1,1,1,2,2,3]
k = 2

def most_frequent(arr, num = 1)
  arr.group_by(&:itself).sort_by {|_,s| -s.length}.first(num).map(&:first)
end

most_frequent(input, k)
```

output:

```
=> [1, 2]
```

**MaxHeap Answer**

```
require "rubygems"
require "algorithms"

include Containers

input = [1,1,1,2,2,3] 
k = 2

def heap_most_frequent(arr, num = 1)
  max_heap = MaxHeap.new(arr.group_by(&:itself).map{|n,ns| [ns.count,n]})
  (1..num).each_with_object([]) { |i, result| result << max_heap.pop[1]}
end
```

**Benchmark:**

```
            user     system      total        real
orig:   0.050000   0.000000   0.050000   (0.057158)
heap:   0.110000   0.000000   0.110000   (0.112387)
```

**Summary**

Most of the work goes in to making the hash, the Heap in this instance just complicates things when dealing with key, value pairs.

Comment: That first line makes sense, but the second chunk is really odd. Instead of `[].tap` why not `(1..num).each_with_object([]) { |i, result|`? That usually results in far less cluttered code.

Comment: @tadman thanks, updated. Still pretty new to Ruby / coding in general, appreciate the critiquing.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. `tap` is pretty useful, just odd to use in this particular situation. Good to know all your tools, though!

Comment: Thank you! Definitely taught me something new about Ruby. But I'm more curious about how one would utilize a maxHeap for this problem. I've never implemented one before-- so I'm curious if this is the right idea. @tadman and OneNeptune

Comment: @Sunny I'll find some good gems that have quality MaxHeap classes for Ruby and update later today.

Comment: Ruby doesn't lend itself to implementing structures like heaps as effectively as more low-level languages like C can. Objects carry a lot more baggage than a simple structure with a few pointers in it. You could try [building one of these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap) but it'd probably be faster to do it in C as a Ruby extension.

Comment: yeah, there's a quality implementation here: https://github.com/kanwei/algorithms that I was going to check out. @Sunny should check it out as well.

Comment: @Sunny I've provided a maxHeap version.

Comment: @OneNeptune It's not a quality implementation. It's bloated, slow and poorly documented. Use this instead: https://github.com/florian/rb_heap

Answer (score 2):

You can always do this with a few *O(n)* transforms with one hash-table intermediate:

```
def max_in_list(list, n = 1)
  list.group_by { |v| v }.sort_by do |_, s|
    -s.length
  end.first(n).map(&:first)
end

numbers = [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6 ]

max_in_list(numbers, 2)
# => [1, 2, 4]
```

Unfortunately `max_by` doesn't respect ordering when requesting more than one entry. It just gives the top *N* without any concern for rank.

Comment: This never uses N, I think you meant to change line 4 to `end.first(n).map(&:first)`

This is a nice method by the way.

Comment: in newer rubies you can also do `.group_by(&:itself)`